# Possible to get Windows 8 Search to look into files other than .txt and .xml?

Tags: windows-explorer, search, windows-8

I'm using Windows 8 Enterprise. I'm a programmer, so I deal with a lot of odd "file types" that are in text. One of these is .xaml, which is basically xml with a different file extension. I'm trying to search for a term in a directory of xaml files, but the only files it seems to check the contents of are the .txt and .xml files in the same directory.

How do I force Windows 8 to look into the content of other file types?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-advanced-indexing-options) works in Windows 7:

1. Open Indexing Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type indexing options, and then click Indexing Options.
2. Click Advanced. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
3. In the Advanced Options dialog box, click the File Types tab.
4. In the Add new extension to list box, type the file name extension (for example, "txt"), and then click Add.
5. Click Index Properties Only or **Index Properties and File Contents**, and then click OK.

[image]

As per [this page](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/windows_8_search-indexing_files-windows_explorer_ribbon-advanced_query_syntax,2-228-3.html), it works the same way on Windows 8 as well.